# Can't get "sudo apt-get update" to work! [NOOB]

Tags: raspbian, ssh, apt, update, sudo

Noob here...

When I run "sudo apt-get update" i get:

```
0% [Connecting to archive.raspbian.org (5.153.255.206) ] [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org (93.93.128.133)]

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://mirrordirector/raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg

Cannot initiate the connection to ...[so on] ... (101: Network is unreachable) ... tries to connect to archive.raspberrypi.org and same thing happen!
```

Pinging Google.com works with 0% loss

Pinging both IPs for mirrordirector.raspbian.org and archive.raspberrypi.org given above works with 0% loss <

Im running a Pi Zero v1.3 clean install jessie-lite
Also noticed that rpi-update returns "command not found".

Im running the PI zero in headless mode over USB WITH Internet (from my PC) like this:
https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget

Any suggestions?

```
sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 usb0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 usb0
```

Comment: are you able to ping archive.raspberrypi.org?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disable Avast!!!

Avast Firewall or some shield was messing up with me...

Comment: How would someone disable it? Why not make a rule that allows what is obviously valid traffic.

Comment: avast on raspbian?..

Comment: @Orphans Presumably this means the problem was not Pi related after all.

Comment: @goldilocks The answer does not make any sence at all.

Comment: @Orphans I dunno.  The question does say it's about a Pi Zero used as an OTG ethernet gadget, meaning traffic was routed through the PC.  On which a firewall or anti-virus software may have created the problem.

Comment: Correct! That was the problem... both Avast and Windows 10 firewall!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a DNS problem too. Can you update **resolv.conf** by:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then add these lines to the file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

which would use Google's DNS server.

Save and reboot and try the apt-get command again and see if this helps.